# TCP Socket doesn't receive Data in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I got the task to create some Chat Client. The server is given and code unknown (only got the executable). The Client/Server communicates via TCP. First the Client connects to the server and sends his username. The Server will answer with some Statuscode. At this state I'm stuck. I created the socket and connect to the server. The server shows, that it receives the username but my client doesn't get any answer.

```
#define MAX_USERNAME    11
#define MAX_MSG_SIZE    1001
#define SERVERIP        "localhost" 
#define SERVERPORT      5000

[...]someFunctions()[...]

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char defaulthost[] =    "localhost";
    hostent                 *host;
    protoent                *protocol;
    SOCKADDR_IN             server_addr;
    SOCKET                  socket_d;
    unsigned short          port;
    char                    *hostname;
    int                     n;
    int                     c;
    int                     connectCode;
    char username[MAX_USERNAME];
    char message[MAX_MSG_SIZE];

    long                        conn;
    long                        msgSize;

    [...]
    //read in username
    [...]

    // Connect to Server

    RNP_Init(); // intializes winsock

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));       
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                   
    port = SERVERPORT;                                  
    if (port > 0){            
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);             
    }
    else {                                              
        fprintf(stdout,"Ungültige Portnummer\n");
        RNP_Cleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    hostname = defaulthost;
    conn = getAddress(hostname,&server_addr);
    if(conn == SOCKET_ERROR){
        fprintf(stdout,"IP fuer %s nicht aufgeloest",hostname);
        RNP_Cleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stdout,"IP aufgeloest");
    }

    socket_d = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (socket_d == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        RNP_Error(RNP_E_SOCK, "Fehler bei Generierung des Sockets\n");
        RNP_Cleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else  {
        fprintf(stdout, "Socket erfolgreich erstellt!\n");
    } 

    conn = connect(socket_d, (SOCKADDR*)&server_addr,sizeof(SOCKADDR));

    if(conn==SOCKET_ERROR){
        printf("Fehler: connect gescheitert, ERROR: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        RNP_Cleanup();
        fprintf(stdout,"Taste druecken zum beenden\n");
        getch();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{
        printf("Verbunden mit Server!!\n");
    }

    while(conn != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stdout,"Sende Nutzernamen...\n");
        send(socket_d, username, strlen(username), 0);
        fprintf(stdout,"Username gesendet: %s mit der Laenge %d\n", username, strlen(username));

        msgSize = recv(socket_d,message,1001,0);
        if(msgSize==0){
            fprintf(stdout,"Verbindung vom Server getrennt\n");
            break;
        }
        if(msgSize==SOCKET_ERROR){
            fprintf(stdout,"Error: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
        message[conn]='\0';
        printf("Server antwortet: %s\n",message);
    }
[...]
```

Comment: You should not assume that the entire response will be received in a single call to `recv()`. TCP does not have message boundaries, and there's no 1-to-1 correspondence between calls to `send` on the server and `recv` on the receiver.

Comment: Your application protocol needs some way to indicate message boundaries, such as where the end of the username is, and the end of the status code sent by the server.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

`message[conn]='\0';`

If `conn` equals 0, you will not be able to "see" the data.
You should not use `conn` but `msgSize`, which contains the number of received bytes.

`message[msgSize]='\0';`

**EDIT:** You should take care of `Barmar`'s advices.